Webscrapping sitio web de enlaces python
Estoy intentando extraer URLs de imágenes de páginas de productos en renuevatucloset.cl, pero mi código no imprime nada. Ya he extraído con éxito los enlaces de los productos de la página principal, pero cuando intento acceder a cada página de producto y extraer las URLs de las imágenes, no se imprime nada. Aquí está mi código:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.renuevatucloset.cl/productos/mujer/calzado/zapatillas'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.6613.114 Safari/537.3"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

product_links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if '/productos/' in link['href']:
        product_links.append(link['href'])

for link in product_links:
    product_url = 'https://www.renuevatucloset.cl' + link
    product_page = requests.get(product_url, headers=headers)
    product_soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page.content, "html.parser")

    for img_tag in product_soup.find_all('img', src=True):
        print(img_tag['src'])

Esperaba ver las URLs de las imágenes de los productos impresas, pero no obtengo ninguna salida. He verificado que product_links no está vacío y que puedo acceder manualmente a las páginas de los productos.
Lo que he intentado:

He comprobado que la lista product_links se llena correctamente.
He verificado manualmente que las páginas de productos contienen etiquetas <img> con atributos src.
He intentado imprimir product_soup para ver si el contenido de la página se está recuperando correctamente.

Mis preguntas son:

¿Por qué mi código no está extrayendo e imprimiendo las URLs de las imágenes?
¿Hay algo específico sobre la estructura de este sitio web que estoy pasando por alto?
¿Cómo puedo modificar mi código para extraer con éxito las URLs de las imágenes de cada página de producto?

Cualquier ayuda u orientación sería muy apreciada. ¡Gracias!

Lo que sucede es que tú le estás haciendo peticiones al sitio web y lo que obtienes es un código HTML.
Si examinamos el HTML que obtenemos como respuesta, podemos notar que no posee una estructura compleja; por el contrario, el body solo consta de scripts.
Deduzco que la página se genera completamente a partir del código Javascript. Por lo tanto no puedes obtener nada relevante.
La diferencia está en el navegador: tu código no usa ningún navegador que interprete el Javascript.
Considera automatizar un navegador. Puedes usar Selenium para eso.
